# Reload Xaml page from ViewModel Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm working on a functionality where I have a ObservableCollection say UserList in ViewModel and which is getting updated dynamically. Now on the total count of users in UserList I want to create the same number of columns in UI (XAML).

Initially there are only 2 columns by default.

Unfortunately calling a constructor in the ViewModel is not working. Any help?

Comment: Is the issue that you are not able to get data loaded into your `ObservableCollection` or are you not able to get the UI looking correct? Please include the code you are currently working with.

Comment: Yes @hvaughan3 its the UI which is not getting updated or reloaded.

Comment: Please show the code you are currently working with so we can tell what might be wrong.